# How to improve the performance of this query Sql in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I have a query in SQL that takes about 15 seconds to return the result, I need to improve the performance, I've worked a few hours and I can't get a satisfactory result.
MySql 5.6 
Table lote: 304053 rows 
Table Prod_lista: 41525 rows 
Time result: 15 Seconds

```
SET @CODIGO_EMPRESA = 1;
SET @CODIGO_FILIAL = 1;
SET @PESQUISA = '%';


SELECT 
    B.CODIGO_PRODUTO,
    C.DESCRICAO,
    B.SALDO_DISPONIVEL,
    B.SALDO_RESERVADO,
    B.SALDO_INDISPONIVEL,
    B.SALDO_TERCEIROS,
    B.SALDO_ENTREGUE,
    C.SITUACAO
FROM
    (SELECT 
        A.CODIGO_EMPRESA,
            A.CODIGO_FILIAL,
            A.CODIGO_PRODUTO,
            SUM(A.SALDO_DISPONIVEL) AS SALDO_DISPONIVEL,
            SUM(A.SALDO_RESERVADO) AS SALDO_RESERVADO,
            SUM(A.SALDO_INDISPONIVEL) AS SALDO_INDISPONIVEL,
            SUM(A.SALDO_TERCEIROS) AS SALDO_TERCEIROS,
            SUM(A.SALDO_ENTREGUE) AS SALDO_ENTREGUE
    FROM
        LOTE A
    WHERE
        A.CODIGO_EMPRESA = @CODIGO_EMPRESA
            AND A.CODIGO_FILIAL = @CODIGO_FILIAL
            AND IFNULL(A.ENCERRADO, 0) = 0
            AND A.TIPO NOT IN (4 , 5)
    GROUP BY A.CODIGO_PRODUTO
    ORDER BY NULL) B
        INNER JOIN
    PROD_LISTA C ON B.CODIGO_EMPRESA = C.CODIGO_EMPRESA
        AND B.CODIGO_FILIAL = C.CODIGO_FILIAL
        AND B.CODIGO_PRODUTO = C.CODIGO
        AND IFNULL(C.SITUACAO, 1) = 1
WHERE
    (B.CODIGO_PRODUTO LIKE @PESQUISA
        OR C.CODIGOFABRICA LIKE @PESQUISA
        OR C.CODIGOBARRA_COMPLETO LIKE @PESQUISA
        OR C.DESCRICAO LIKE @PESQUISA
        OR EXISTS( SELECT 
            D.CODIGOPRODUTO
        FROM
            PROD_CODIGO_BARRA D
        WHERE
            D.CODIGO_EMPRESA = @CODIGO_EMPRESA
                AND D.CODIGO_FILIAL = @CODIGO_FILIAL
                AND B.CODIGO_PRODUTO = D.CODIGOPRODUTO
                AND D.CODIGOBARRA_COMPLETO LIKE @PESQUISA))
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Structure of the batch table

```
CREATE TABLE `lote` (
  `CODIGO_EMPRESA` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CODIGO_FILIAL` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CODIGO_LOTE` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CODIGO_LOTE_PAI` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMERO_LOTE` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIPO` int(2) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `DATAHORA` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CODIGO_DOCUMENTO` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CODIGO_ITEM` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTO` decimal(21,10) DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `CODIGO_PRODUTO` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESTINO_INICIAL` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SALDO_INICIAL` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `SALDO_DISPONIVEL` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `SALDO_INDISPONIVEL` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `SALDO_TERCEIROS` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `SALDO_RESERVADO` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `SALDO_ENTREGUE` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `VENCIMENTO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENCERRADO` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `CODIGO_CONTAGEM` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CODIGO_LOTE`),
  KEY `IDX_CODIGO_LOTE` (`CODIGO_LOTE`),
  KEY `IDX_CODIGO_PRODUTO` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CODIGO_PRODUTO`),
  KEY `IDX_CONSULTA_PDV` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CODIGO_PRODUTO`,`ENCERRADO`,`TIPO`),
  KEY `IDX_CONTAGEM_ESTOQUE` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CODIGO_PRODUTO`,`TIPO`,`ENCERRADO`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTO` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CUSTO`),
  KEY `IDX_DOCUMENTO_ITEM` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CODIGO_DOCUMENTO`,`CODIGO_ITEM`),
  KEY `IDX_EMPRESA_FILIAL` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`),
  KEY `IDX_ESTOQUE` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`TIPO`,`ENCERRADO`),
  KEY `IDX_FILTRO` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CODIGO_LOTE`,`DATAHORA`),
  KEY `IDX_LOTE_COMP` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`CODIGO_PRODUTO`,`DATAHORA`),
  KEY `IDX_TIPO` (`TIPO`),
  KEY `IDX_TIPO_CODIGO` (`CODIGO_EMPRESA`,`CODIGO_FILIAL`,`TIPO`,`CODIGO_PRODUTO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[image: Result explain]

How can I improve SQL to have a faster result?

Answer (score 1):

- `OR` is a performance killer; try to avoid it.
- `B.CODIGO_PRODUTO LIKE "%"` is equivalent to `TRUE`, but the Optimizer does not see that.  It would be much better to construct the query dynamically instead of using @variables and picking values that eliminate clauses.
- Also of importance is that the Optimizer *may* be able to use an index when there is *not* a leading wildcard:

  ```
  x LIKE 'A%'  -- possibly uses index
  x LIKE '%'    -- cannot use index
  x LIKE '%B'    -- cannot use index
  x LIKE '@foo'    -- cannot use index
  ```
- `int(4)` -- the `(4)` is irrelevant.  All `INTs` are the same 4-byte datatype.  See `SMALLINT` and similar ones for smaller datatypes.
- Don't blindly use `NULL` (most of your columns are `NULLable`); leave `NULL` for optional / unknown / etc, values.
- `IFNULL(A.ENCERRADO, 0) = 0` -- If you can arrange for this to have 2 values (0 and 1), you can simplify this expression and avoid using a function.  Functions make expressions not 'sargable'.  Once you have done that, the suggested index below may be useful.
- When you have `INDEX(a,b,c)`, there is no need for also having `INDEX(a,b)`.  For example:  `IDX_EMPRESA_FILIAL` can be dropped.
- These indexes *may* help:

  ```
  D:  (CODIGOPRODUTO, CODIGO_FILIAL, CODIGO_EMPRESA, CODIGOBARRA_COMPLETO)
  A:  (ENCERRADO, CODIGO_FILIAL, TIPO, CODIGO_EMPRESA)
  ```
- There may be more suggestions.  Apply most of the above, then come back for more suggestions.  (And provide the other `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.)

Answer (score 1):

Correlated subqueries, like your EXISTS one, can be costly if they are correlated with a large number of results from the outer query. I'd suggest converting your EXISTS condition into something like this:

```
OR B.CODIGO_PRODUTO IN (
      SELECT D.CODIGOPRODUTO
      FROM PROD_CODIGO_BARRA AS D
      WHERE D.CODIGO_EMPRESA = @CODIGO_EMPRESA
         AND D.CODIGO_FILIAL = @CODIGO_FILIAL
         AND D.CODIGOBARRA_COMPLETO LIKE @PESQUISA
   )
```

With your correlated version, the subquery ends up being evaluated separately for every row coming out of the main FROM. But with this non-correlated version, the subquery is only evaluated once, and it's result set is used to check the rows coming out of the main FROM.